# Is tensor.op a copy or a reference?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to determine if the operation returned by a call to mytensor.op is a copy of the operation node that generated it, or in fact a reference.

The reason I need to know is that if I have a split node (node with two child tensors), and I am traversing the graph -- if I call child1_tensor.op will I receive a different object than if I call child2_tensor.op ? Or will these both return a reference to the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should return the same operation. I'm fairly sure nodes in the graph are immutable once they've been added, so there's no need to defensively copy. You can always check using the `is` operator.

```
def f(x):
  return x - 1, x + 1

x = tf.zeros((), dtype=tf.float32)
y, z = tf.py_func(f, (x,), (tf.float32, tf.float32))
print(y.op is z.op)  # True
```